# How to show answer buttons after add button has been clicked on?

Tags: php, javascript

I have an application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text16.php) where an user is able to select their options and answers. The best way to explain you the question is if you use the application itself so you can see what is happening. Please follow steps below in application.

- Step 1: When you open application, you will see the "Open Grid" link,
  click on it and select an option type, after you select an option it
  will display the answer buttons at the bottom. For example if the
  option you choose is "5", it will display 5 answer buttons "A - E",
  if option chose is 8, it will display 8 answer buttons "A-H".

Now this is fine. But the problem I have is if the user wants to add a previous option. please look at steps below:

- Step 2: Refresh the page
- Step 3: You will see a green plus button on left hand side, click on
  it, this will open up a modal window.
- Step 4: In the search box type in "AAA" and then click on "Submit"
  button, it will display rows from the database.
- Step 5: Please select a row by clicking on the "Add" button, the
  modal window will close and if you look at the answer and option
  control on the right hand side, you can see that the Option Type
  textbox and Number of Answers textbox appears, but the "Answer"
  buttons do not appear.

So my question is how can I get the "Answer" buttons to appear after the user has clicked on the "Add" button?

Below is function where it controls what happens after the "Add" button has been clicked on:

```
function addwindow(numberAnswer,gridValues) { 

    if(window.console) console.log();

    if($(plusbutton_clicked).attr('id')=='mainPlusbutton') { 


        $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer);
        $('#mainGridTxt').val(gridValues);
        } else { 
            $(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').find('input.numberAnswerTxtRow').val(numberAnswer);
            $(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').find('input.gridTxtRow').val(gridValues);
            }

    $.modal.close(); 
    return false;
}
```

Below is the code where the answer buttons are stored (What do I need to call on to be able to show the answer buttons):

```
<table id="optionAndAnswer" class="optionAndAnswer">

...

<?php
    $a = range("A","Z");
?>

<table id="answerSection">
    <tr>

<?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach($a as $key => $val){
        if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
        echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\">";      
        if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>
<input class="answerBtns answers" name="answerTrueName"  id="answerTrue"    type="button"   value="True"    onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
<input class="answerBtns answers" name="answerFalseName" id="answerFalse"   type="button"   value="False"   onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
<input class="answerBtns answers" name="answerYesName"   id="answerYes"     type="button"   value="Yes"     onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
<input class="answerBtns answers" name="answerNoName"    id="answerNo"      type="button"   value="No"      onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
...
</table>
```

UPDATE:

Below is the code where it imports the answer buttons after an option is selected from the grid:

```
       $('.gridBtns').on('click', function()

    {

    appendAnswers(this);

});

function appendAnswers(t){
var clickedNumber = t.value;

        $(t).closest('.option').siblings('.numberAnswer').find('.answertxt').show();
        $(t).closest('.option').siblings('.numberAnswer').find('.string').hide();



         $(t).closest('.option').siblings('.answer').find('.answers').each(function(index) {
            if (!isNaN(clickedNumber) && index < clickedNumber) {
                $(t).show();
                $(t).closest('.option').siblings('.numberAnswer').find('.string').hide();


         // show but don't change the value
         $(t).closest('.option').siblings('.numberAnswer').find('.answertxt').show();


            } else {

                $(t).hide();
                $(t).removeClass('answerBtnsOn');
                $(t).addClass('answerBtnsOff');

            }

            var $this = $(t);
             var context = $this.parents('.optionAndAnswer');
             console.log($this);


        });

        prevButton = clickedNumber;


            $(t).closest('.option').siblings('.noofanswers').find('.string').hide();     
            $(t).closest('.option').siblings('.noofanswers').find('.answertxt').show();


        getButtons();

    };
});



    function getButtons()
    {
        var i;
        if (initClick == 0) {
            for (i = 65; i <= 90; i++) { // iterate over character codes for A to Z
                $("#answer" + String.fromCharCode(i)).removeClass("answerBtnsOn").addClass("answerBtnsOff");

            }

            initClick = 1;
        }
        // code above makes sure all buttons start off with class answerBtnsOff, (so all button are white).
    }
```

Comment: What function do you call to import the 'answer' when you clicked on a integer in the 'Open Grid' section? I assume it should be the same function. Please provide a little bit more code. I am to lazy to search through your whole script ;)

Comment: @Jelmer I included an update where it includes the functions where it imports answer buttons depending on the option selected from the grid

Comment: Just call the same function as you use for the click on a .gridBtns. Make the function as his own function, and call it with the property (this) so it know what data to use. I guess that's the solver. Just run that function again (maybe you have to modify it a bit in order to work for both buttons)

Comment: @Jelmer Put this in an answer so if you are correct I can mark it. So what you are saying is that in the addwindow function just call  `$('.gridBtns').on('click', function())`? IS that correct way of calling the whole function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: "this" needed to be passes as an object, try edited code

Pull out the function from the onClick like this and then call it like "getChoice(4);" when the history page fires the add button.

Rewrite like this:

```
function getChoice(obj){

    var clickedNumber = this.value;

    $(obj).closest('.option').siblings('.numberAnswer').find('.answertxt').show();
    $(obj).closest('.option').siblings('.numberAnswer').find('.string').hide();



     $(obj).closest('.option').siblings('.answer').find('.answers').each(function(index) {
        if (!isNaN(clickedNumber) && index < clickedNumber) {
            $(obj).show();
            $(obj).closest('.option').siblings('.numberAnswer').find('.string').hide();


     // show but don't change the value
     $(obj).closest('.option').siblings('.numberAnswer').find('.answertxt').show();


        } else {

            $(obj).hide();
            $(obj).removeClass('answerBtnsOn');
            $(obj).addClass('answerBtnsOff');

        }

        var $this = $(obj);
         var context = $this.parents('.optionAndAnswer');
         console.log($this);


    });


    getButtons();

}



$('.gridBtns').on('click', function(){

getChoice(this);
});
```

Comment: I will test it :) and get back to u

Comment: I have tested this but no answer buttons appear at all after an option is selected

Comment: I reedited.. it was calling a reference to "this" so I changed it to pass this as an object.. see if that worked

Comment: the code you have on your site .. I checked with firebug.. isnt the one passing this as an object... try the newest edit

Comment: It has not worked at all, it doesn't display any answer buttons when user has selected option from grid (this did work in my old code), never mind displaying answer buttons after clicking on "Add" button. Funny thing is what your code is doing is that if I can click on an option button from the grid such as "6", the number "6" option button suddenly disappears from the grid when I open up the grid again lol

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really too sure if I understand your question completely, but I tried out your application a few times and I think I understand:
Load a result from the database -> populate fields with the result ?

Anyway, I see you're using Jquery, so I think you should be able to use .html() or .append() to add each button in a for loop: (I assume you've stored your answer buttons in an array).
I'm lazy so I usually name targets with an ID #ButtonHolder is your  for the buttons.

```
var buttonhtml = ""; //I personally like to build the html then insert it. 
var lastchar = gridValues.charCodeAt(gridvalues.length-1);
for (i=65;i<=lastchar;i++) // 65 is the code for "A"
buttonhtml += "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\""+String.fromCharCode(i)+"\" id=\"answer"+String.fromCharCode(i)+"\" name=\"answer"+String.fromCharCode(i)+"Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOn\">";
$("#ButtonHolder").html(buttonhtml);
```

Have you thought about instead of using onclick, using JQuery to handle the clicks with a class?

Edit:

```
function addwindow(questionText,textWeight,numberAnswer,gridValues) { 



    if(window.console) console.log();

    if($(plusbutton_clicked).attr('id')=='mainPlusbutton') { 

        if( gridValues != "True or False" && gridValues != "Yes or No" )
{
   var myNumbers = {};
   myNumbers["A-C"] = "3";
   myNumbers["A-D"] = "4";
   myNumbers["A-E"] = "5";
//...
   myNumbers["A-Z"] = "26";
   gridValues = myNumbers[gridValues];
   $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').show();

}
else{
   $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').hide();
}

        $('#mainTextarea').val(questionText); 
        $('#mainTxtWeight').val(textWeight);
        $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer);
        $('#mainGridTxt').val(gridValues);
        } else { 
            $(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').find('input.numberAnswerTxtRow').val(numberAnswer);


$(plusbutton_clicked).closest('tr').find('input.gridTxtRow').val(gridValues);

    var lastchar = gridValues.charCodeAt(gridValues.length-1); // getting the last charcode i.e. "A-D" -> "D" -> 68
   $(".ansBtns").removeClass("answerBtnsOn").addClass("answerBtnsOff"); // reset all the buttons to off *I think this works* 
    // 65 is the code for "A" Iterating each choice and activating it:
    for (i=65;i<=lastchar;i++)
    $("#answer"+String.charCodeAt(i)).addClass("answerBtnsOn");    
        $.modal.close(); 
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Do I just need to include this block of code in the "addwindow" function()? In future I won't use onclick and use jquery to handle the click with the class :)

Comment: You should put this in the section where you get your results from the query. However, I noticed that all of your buttons are there, and you're just hiding inactive ones, if you use this code, it will overwrite all the hidden buttons and only show the ones selected. I just noticed you use 'A-D' for your add, not an array. There are lots of ways to get around this I'll edit my answer.

Comment: By the way, if it's just a matter of turning it to buttonson or turning it to buttonsoff you can probably use the same idea, but iterate through your buttons instead of editing the html

Comment: I cannot gt your code to work, Can you show me in your answer how you would implement your code into my code because I think I am doing it incorrectly. Probably coz its 12:40am where I am and Im just getting tired because I am just struggling to think lol :)

Comment: This should turn off BtnsOn and then turn on each one that needs it.

Comment: Thanks for code but it did not work. What happens with your code is that if I click on the "Add" button, it does not close the modal window as it did previously and it doesn't change anything, doesn't change option type and number of answers (which it did do previously), never mind not displaying/changing answer buttons. Good effort though appreciate the help but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, whats firing when you click on an option in the grid? if the name of the object that has the properties of what your looking for is named based off of the option type:
i.e. "option type 4" is "op4" then,
instead of having the "Previous Questions" query populate the field, have it store the values it returns as vars, then just call the same function that populates the answers when you click the option in the popup:

```
optionPicked("op" + opType);
```

or however you called it.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the same function as you use for the click on a .gridBtns. 
Make the function as his own function, and call it with the property (this) so it knows what data to use. I guess that's the solver. Just run that function again (maybe you have to modify it a bit in order to work for both buttons)

In order to do this. Make to eventlisteners, one for .gridBtns and one for the .addBtn.

When .gridBtns or .addBtns is called, just run the function in the eventlistener as:

```
$('.gridBtns').on('click', function(){
  appendAnswers(this);
});
```

and modify your function you used before to something like:

```
function appendAnswers(t){
  //t = this you defined in the onclick event
  //rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: I am a little confused as to what you want me to put in the appendAnswers(t) function. I don't quite understand what you mean?

Comment: You have to add what you have in your $('.gridBtns').on('click', function(){ !!THIS CODE !! }); right now and change the 'this' to 't'

Comment: Oh I can see what you mean now. I will try out the code and get back to you

Comment: I have tested your code but it does not display any answer buttons after I have selected an option or click on the "Add" button. I have updated the code in my question so you can see how I implemented your code. I think I have done it correct but feel free to check to make sure :)

Comment: It should work for the gridBtns. Use firebug or a similar tool to debug your code. I think you missed a small detail somewhere.

Comment: I will firebug it and see what is happening, am I suppose to change `onclick=\"btnclick(this);` to `onclick=\"btnclick(t);`?

Comment: I tried changing the onclick to what I thought I shud change it but no luck. No errors on firebug, the code doesn't add display answer buttons after option selected from grid or after "Add" button, instead when I click on an option button from the grid such as "5", if I reopen the grid, option 5 is then missing from the grid

Comment: Maybe it's best to start over and think about the script for a sec. Now you know what works and what doesn't, maybe it's best to start over and plan your code carefully. It will help you a lot if you have a plan in your mind or better, on paper so you can stick to that. Coding without a design can be hard and you will get from one problem into the other. (Yes, I have spent many nights like that ;) )